# Azure automaticaly deploys update

Tags: azure

I have create an ASP.NET Core web app in Azure.

I have followed this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-linux

Everything works, but I have create a new develop branch. Each time i push something in the branch, the deployment script is fired. Fortunately, it only deploys master branch on production. So if i have no merged files on master, it deploys the same files. But it might cut the website during a few seconds.

Is there a way to avoid the deployment when i am pushing something on develop branch ?

Thanks

Comment: What branch is listed under deployment center? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment  You might need to disconnect/reconnect to github now that you added a branch.

Comment: This is not github, this is kudu